# Exclude child of specific class when jQuery automatically adds prettyPhoto class to links

Tags: jquery, image, parent, prettyphoto

I'm using jQuery to add `class="prettyPhoto"` to all links that are both inside of `<div class="entry-content">` and that contain an image.

```
$('.entry-content a').has('img').addClass('prettyPhoto');
```

The code works well; however I am having trouble adapting it to exclude any links located within `<div class="hover_link">` and I can't figure out how.

After fiddling around I have the following which is producing wierd results:

```
if(!$('.entry-content a').parent('.hover_link')) {
    $('.entry-content a').has('img').addClass('prettyPhoto');
}
```

Some sample html:

```
<div class="entry-content">

    <!-- prettyPhoto should be added to the next link -->
    <a href="whatever"><img src="whatever.jpg"></a>

    <!-- prettyPhoto shouldn't be added to the next link (there's no img) -->
    <a href="whatever">Some Text</a>

    <div class="hover_link">
        <!-- prettyPhoto shouldn't be added inside of .hover_link -->
        <a href="whatever"><img src="whatever.jpg"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery's `not` :

```
$('.entry-content a').not('.hover_link a').addClass('prettyPhoto');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I needed. I added '.has("img")' to make: '$('.entry-content a').not('.hover_link a').has('img').addClass('prettyPhoto');'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.entry-content a').has('img').each(function() {
  if($(this).parent('hover_link').length == 0) $(this).addClass('prettyPhoto');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helps me too as I just learned something.  Much appreciated.